# Base R Graphics: Point-range and Ribbon

Tags: r, plot

How do you draw point-range and ribbon plots in base R graphics?

Here are two `ggplot2` plots that I would like to reproduce without dependencies beyond the basic R installation. I do *not* need to reproduce any theme elements or labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)

# point range
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl), mtcars)
dat <- data.frame(names(coef(mod)), coef(mod), confint(mod)) |>
    setNames(c("x", "y", "ymin", "ymax"))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
    geom_pointrange()
```

[image: img1]

```r
# ribbon
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
pre <- predictions(mod)
ggplot(pre, aes(x = hp, y = estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .3)
```

[image: img2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### First

I think everything here is self explanatory, so just showing the result:

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(1, nrow(dat)), ylim = range(dat[,-1]))
grid()

points(1:nrow(dat), dat$y)
segments(1:nrow(dat), dat$ymin, 1:nrow(dat), dat$ymax)

axis(1, at = 1:nrow(dat), dat$x)
axis(2, las = 2)

title("point-range", adj=0)
title(ylab = "beta")
```

[image: first]

##### Second

Here the main issue is plotting the polygon. Polygon joins all the points one by one, so they will have to be ordered. Hence I order the data.frame first:

```
pre <- pre[order(pre$hp),]
```

After that it should be clear:

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = range(pre$hp), ylim = range(pre$conf.low, pre$conf.high))
grid()

polygon(c(pre$hp, rev(pre$hp)), c(pre$conf.low, rev(pre$conf.high)),
        col = adjustcolor("cornflowerblue", 0.3))

axis(1, lwd = 0)
axis(2, lwd = 0, las=2)

title("Ribbon", adj = 0)
title(xlab = "hp")
title(ylab = "estimate")
```

[image: second]